# SQL: Compare if a value exist in another table and vice versa

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by, pivot

I have two tables:

```
**Table1**

COD_1    DATE
001      05/10/2020
002      05/11/2020
003      05/12/2020

**Table2**

COD_2   Date
001     12/12/2008 
002     12/11/2008 
008     12/09/2008
```

I would like to compare the COD column of Table1 with the COD column of Table2. Each value of these two columns is never repeated.
So I would like to create a third table that shows the CODs, two columns named col_Table1 and col_Table2 and their respective dates. Each of these columns (col_Table1 and col_Table2) informing whether the respective COD is in table 1 or table 2, or in both tables.
The final table should be something like this:

```
COD_newTable    col_Table1  col_Table2  DATE_table1  DATE_table2
001              Yes         Yes        05/10/2020   12/12/2008
002              Yes         Yes        05/11/2020   12/11/2008
003              Yes         No         05/12/2020
008              No          Yes                     12/09/2008
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join` in SQL Server:

```
select coalesce(t1.cod_1, t2.cod_2) as cod,
       (case when t1.cod_1 is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as in_1,
       (case when t2.cod_1 is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as in_2,
       t1.date as date_1,
       t2.date as date_2
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.cod_1 = t2.cod_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `full join`:

```
select
    coalesce(t1.cod_1, t2.cod_2) cod_new_table,
    case when t1.cod_1 is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end col_table1,
    case when t2.cod_2 is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end col_table2,
    t1.date date_table1,
    t2.date date_table2
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2 on t1.cod_1 = t2.cod_2
```

---

MS Access, which you finally tagged your question with, supports neither `full join` nor `case`. For your dataset, an alternative is `union all` and conditional aggregation with `iif()`:

```
select
    cod_new_table,
    max(iif(which = 1, 'Yes', 'No')) col_table1,
    max(iif(which = 2, 'Yes', 'No')) col_table2,
    max(date_table1) date_table1,
    max(date_table2) date_table2
from (
    select 1 which, cod_1 cod_new_table, date date_table1, null date_table2 from table1
    union all
    select 2, cod_2, null, date from table2
) t
group by cod_new_table
```